# Div alignment with content

Tags: html, css

I'm having some troubles to align the `upper_nav`div with the `content` div.
I want the `upper_nav` with links aligned with the right-hand side margin and that grows in the left-hand side direction depending on how many links there are inside and the width of each boxes.
Could you check which is the problem?

`upper_nav` is child of `header` that takes the whole width of the page:

```
div#upper_nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:80%;
}
```

So I would that the width would be the `80%` of the parent width but I don't understand why the margin is not aligned correctly.

Here the example of my page:

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 17px;
}

body {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-align: justify;
  background-image: url('url_immagine');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

div#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

div#header {
  /*background: url('header.png') no-repeat center center;*/
  /*background-size: cover;*/
  /*height:18vw;*/
  position: relative;
}

div#upper_nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 80%;
  /*background-color:#e6e6e6;*/
}

div#navigation_left {
  padding: 1% 1%;
  float: left;
  width: 21%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888888;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
}

div#content {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-left: 25%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888888;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
}

div#footer {
  clear: both;
  /*background: url('footer.png') no-repeat center center;*/
  /*background-size: cover;*/
  /*height:5vw;*/
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

div#footer_content {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -50%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

P {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0066FF;
  font-size: 17px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #0066FF;
  text-decoration: underline
}

h1 {
  background-color: #737373;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 200%;
}

h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
h7,
h8 {
  background-color: #737373;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 150%;
}

ul#menu_header {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#menu_header li {
  background-color: #737373;
  right: 0;
  width: 19.6%;
  margin: 0.2%;
  float: left;
  /* elementi su singola riga */
}

ul#menu_header li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu_header li.active,
ul#menu_header li:hover {
  background-color: #b1b1b1;
}

ul#menu_left {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 5%;
}

ul#menu_left li {
  margin: 1%;
  font-size: 5vw;
}

ul#menu_left li a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu_left li.active,
ul#menu_left li:hover {
  background-color: #c9c9c9;
}

.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel a {
  color: #000
}

.panel a:hover {
  background-color: #b1b1b1
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x900" width="100%" alt="Riunione annuale GTTI SIEm2019" />
      <div id="upper_nav">
        <ul id="menu_header">
          <li class="active"><a href="../test2/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link11</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link22</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link33</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link44</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation_left">
      <ul id="menu_left"><a href="#">links</a></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div id="footer_content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You notice the non-alignment resizing the window.

Comment: You mean you want the #content to be the same width as the #menu_header? Please note that #upper_nav is pretty much invisible; what you see is the #menu_header inside, which isn't as wide.

Comment: Why not? The idea of #upper_nav was to use it as container so I could set everything in there and then for #menu_header just the parts regartding the list.
I could also do what your're asking. Now the idea was just align #content and #upper_nav in the right-hand side. While leave the left-hand side of #upper_nav do whatever he wants. Otherwise I like also the idea of putting the same length of #content. Is the same

Comment: Can't you put both #menu_header and #content in the same container; then you can give them both full width.